# -lomp not found for openmp apple m1

Tags: clang, openmp, apple-m1

I am currently trying to compile a cpp program with openmp. From what I have read online this is the command that I need to use for indeed using openmp on apple silicon:

```
g++ -Xpreprocessor -fopenmp  -I/opt/homebrew/Cellar/libomp/14.0.6/include -L/usr/local/lib -lomp  heat2D.cpp
```

I have installed everything required for openmp (libomp,llvm,etc...) but it gives me this error:

```
ld: library not found for -lomp
clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)
```

In addition if try to remove the lomp flag:

```
g++ -Xpreprocessor -fopenmp -I/opt/homebrew/Cellar/libomp/14.0.6/include heat2D.cpp
```

this is the error i get:

```
Undefined symbols for architecture arm64:
  "_omp_set_num_threads", referenced from:
      _main in heat2D-0b5aaa.o
ld: symbol(s) not found for architecture arm64
clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)
```

Comment: Try a search :-) https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=openmp+mac+m1
And, if you are asking, give more details. How have you installed the things you have installed? Using brew? Or another package manager? What is "g++", is it *really* the GNU compiler, or merely Apple's symbolic link to their compiler?

Comment: @JimCownie Thank you for answer, I indeed did check and I found nothing useful or at least nothing that helps me out. I did use brew to install both gcc and libomp as well as llvm. g++ is the c++ compiler that I use, I try with clang++ as well but I have the same issue!

Comment: From what you show above, it really looks as if you're still executing Apple's symbolic link for g++, (to clang), rather than the real g++. (Note what reports the linkage error... "clang: error: linker"). So show us the output of ”g++ --version" and "which g++"...

Answer (score 0):

Since you mention that you installed GCC (and LLVM) via Homebrew, the problem is probably (as Jim Cownie suggested) that when you type "g++", you are running the default link to *Apple's* LLVM installation (which, alas, does not support OpenMP).

The problem is that Homebrew installs its versions of the compiler binary commands using versioned names -- e.g., "g++-12" if you installed the latest version of GCC. So you have to use *those* names if you want to run the Homebrew versions. (They are probably installed in /opt/homebrew/bin/ in your case, since you have an Apple Silicon Mac.)

(I haven't installed Homebrew's version of LLVM, but it's probably a similar situation for that as well, since you wouldn't want it to overwrite Apple's LLVM commands.)